# Delete text after animation

Tags: android, animation, android-edittext

in my code I have an EditText called soluzione and I animate it with this code:

```
textColorAnim = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(soluzione, "textColor", Color.RED, Color.WHITE);
textColorAnim.setDuration(100);
textColorAnim.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());
textColorAnim.setRepeatCount(4);
textColorAnim.setRepeatMode(ValueAnimator.REVERSE);
textColorAnim.start();
```

but when the animation ends i want to delete the text in the EditText, how can i do this?

Comment: I have edited your question because you are asking about *android development*, not the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Delete edittext

```
   EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
   editText.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Delete text in edittext

```
   editText.setText("");
```

Comment: I know how to delete it, but in the code where should i put it? The problem is that if i place it after the startAnimation, this one doesn't work. i thought about a thread but I dont know if It's correct.